# Запрос данных из БД со связью многие ко многим

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я создал три таблицы. Мне требуется взять все треки пользователя с определенным api_key. Как должен выглядеть SQL запрос?
БД - postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE users(
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,
            first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
            is_active BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
            api_key UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
        );

        CREATE TABLE albums(
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
            metadata JSONB,
            created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
            updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
        );

        CREATE TABLE tracks(
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR(40),
            album_id INTEGER REFERENCES albums(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
            created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
            updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
        );
```

Comment: Обычный join (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) всех 3х таблиц.

Comment: Я попытался написать `SELECT * FROM tracks INNER JOIN albums ON albums.user_id = 2;` и мне выдалось всё, но только в двойном размере, то есть записи продублировались. Не могли бы вы привести пример, как правильнее будет сделать? Буду благодарен.

Comment: В on должно быть указано условие объединения таблиц. Т.е. какое поле второй таблицы какому полю из первой должно быть равно. А без таких условий он перемножает каждую запись из первой таблицы на все записи из второй. Присмотритесь к примерам в той статье на вики. там везде есть условия объединения. А что касается условия user_id=2 то его более правильным было бы писать в where

Comment: Спасибо, вроде разобрался. Не понимал, что за условие ON.